# Google Sheet & Form: Named Range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms

So I'm using Google Sheets and Google Forms, and in Google Sheets, I'm using a **VLOOKUP** formula like this: `=IF(B3="","",VLOOKUP(B3, tickID,5,false))` where **tickID** is a named range. The **tickID** is set to `'Form Responses 1'!A2:G102`, however it changes to `'Form Responses 1'!A3:G102` when I receive a response.

Can somebody help me? Thank you!

Comment: I think it is a known (unsolved) issue. **Solution**: don't use named ranges, but actual ranges `'Form Responses 1'!A2:G102`

Comment: @Nabnub I tried using it and it changes to A3 also.

Comment: Use `'Form Responses 1'!A:G`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use full-column references:

```
'Form Responses 1'!A:G
```